# Lightweight Java XML parsing/rendering loop

Tags: java, xml

I need to extract an XML document from an `InputStream` and to make it available in a `String` (I can’t modify this signature):

```
String extractXml(InputStream in) {
  // TODO
}
```

I have two problems:

- I don’t want to assume that the XML is UTF-8 (or whatever) encoded.
- I want to remove the `encoding` attribute in the XML declaration (if it’s present) because it doesn’t make any sense for the text representation of an XML document.

Is there a way of doing this without going through a full XML parsing/rendering loop? I’m not interested in validating the XML syntax beyond the XML declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Take a look at [XmlStreamReader from commons-io](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/XmlStreamReader.html) in order to suggest encoding.
2. You may want to completely remove XML declaration. Well-formed XML document without xml declaration is still valid. You could do it with regexp `\\<\\?xml(.+?)\\?\\>`

Your code could be like:

```
String extractXml(InputStream in) {
    // IOUtils is a util class from commons-io
    String xml = IOUtils.toString(new XmlStreamReader(in));
    xml=xml.replaceAll("\\<\\?xml(.+?)\\?\\>", "").trim();
    return xml
}
```

Comment: Removing the XML declaration could have side effects (`encoding` is not the only attribute); and I’m fussy about using regexps for XML parsing. Not a bit risk though, thanks for your answer!